# How to convert column datatype varchar to boolean in snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
SQL compilation error: cannot change column test1 from type BOOLEAN to VARCHAR(255);

SQL compilation error: cannot change column test2 from type VARCHAR(16777216) to VARCHAR(255)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean from VARCHAR to BOOLEAN, it's pretty simple:

```
select 'true'::boolean, cast('False' as BOOLEAN);
-----------------+--------------------------+
 'TRUE'::BOOLEAN | CAST('FALSE' AS BOOLEAN) |
-----------------+--------------------------+
 TRUE            | FALSE                    |
-----------------+--------------------------+
```

However, based on your error messages, you probably mean from BOOLEAN to VARCHAR. Seems this is currently unsupported for some weird reason. I filed an internal ticket to fix it.

In the meantime, you can work around this by doing one of:

```
SELECT IFF(boolean_column, 'TRUE', 'FALSE') ...
SELECT '' || boolean_column ...
```